# How to use slider as progress bar and volume control in kivy python using kv file not main python file

Tags: python, file, kivy, slider, kivymd

I want to create slider by file kv Not with the main Python file I was trying to program the code but it didn't turn out like I expected.

file py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.animation import Animation

class ManagImage(Screen):

    s=SoundLoader.load("mm.mp3")
    a=s.play()
    lang=s.length
    sl=s.get_pos()
    

    def release(self,va):
        self.sl = self.s.get_pos()
        self.s.seek(int(va))
        self.s.play()
        self.slide.text=str((format((va/60),".2f")))
        self.ids.lb.font_size=int(100)


class slider(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "slider"

slider().run()
```

File Kv

```
ManagImage:
    slide:lb
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding:10
        spacing:10
        size:root.size
        pos:root.pos


        Label:
            id : lb

        Slider:

            id : sd
            pos_hint:{"right":1}
            min: 0
            max: root.lang
            step: 1
            value:root.sl

            value_track:True
            value_track_color:(150/255,60/255/10/255,1)



            orientation: "horizontal"
            on_value:root.release(self.value)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what the code sample produced and what was expected.

Comment: What I want is for the slider to advance with the progression of the music file, but about doing that, but when I run the program, the slider is fixed and does not move, and I have my expectations that the tape is moving forward with the progression of the music file. Do you understand what I want now or what?

Comment: You question mentions a volume control. Are you trying to add another `Slider` as a volume control?

Comment: No, this is not what I want. I want the slider to advance with the progression of the music file. I mean, for example, when playing the music file, the slider starts to advance automatically with the progression of the music file. This is what I want to do To further clarify I want when calling the library soundloader and play the music file Combine soundloader.get_pos() with the value of the slider so that the slider advances with the progression of the music file

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by scheduling a method that fetches the audio position of the sound at specific intervals. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

kv = '''
ManagImage:
    slide:lb
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding:10
        spacing:10
        size:root.size
        pos:root.pos

        Label:
            id : lb

        Slider:
            id : sd
            pos_hint:{"right":1}
            min: 0
            max: root.lang
            step: 1
            value:root.sl
            value_track:True
            value_track_color:(150/255,60/255/10/255,1)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            # on_value:root.release(self.value)  # not needed and causes an infinite loop
'''


class ManagImage(Screen):
    sl = NumericProperty(0)
    lang = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ManagImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # start the sound playing
        self.s = SoundLoader.load("test.mp3")
        self.s.play()
        self.lang = self.s.length
        # schedule a method to update the self.sl every half second
        self.sched = Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_audio_pos, 0.5)

    def get_audio_pos(self, dt):
        self.sl = self.s.get_pos()


class slider(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "slider"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


slider().run()
```

The `get_audio_pos()` method updates the `sl` property regularly and the `Slider` automatically updates since the `kv` sets its `value` to that `Property`.

The `release()` method was removed (along with its mention in `kv`) since it is not needed and will cause an infinite loop.

I have included the `kv` as a string in my code just for my own convenience. It can be used in a separate `kv` file just as well.